# How to get country code from country name

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get the country code by passing in the country name.

For example I have the country Canada, I want to get the country code CA.

I need this conversion because I want to use a country flag flutter package that gets the flag based on the passed in country code.

I know I can hard code a map that will do this conversion for me but I am looking for something simpler

Comment: In what way is a map not *simple* ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to, maybe you can parse the json from a metadata tool, like [DataHub](https://datahub.io/core/country-list#python)? [CSV](https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/country-list/data_csv/data/d7c9d7cfb42cb69f4422dec222dbbaa8/data_csv.csv).

Comment: The answer is way more difficult than the one proposed by the question creator.